# Rename Columns of several dataframes

Tags: python

code below, I have multiple dataframes with the same structure and would like to change the column names.

```
import pandas as pd

data_1 = [[1, 'tom', 10], [2, 'nick', 15], [3, 'juli', 14]] 
data_2 = [[1, 'tom', 10], [2, 'nick', 15], [3, 'juli', 14]]  
data_3 = [[1, 'tom', 10], [2, 'nick', 15], [3, 'juli', 14]]  

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1, columns = ['number', 'Name', 'Age']) 
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2, columns = ['number', 'Name', 'Age']) 
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(data_3, columns = ['number', 'Name', 'Age']) 

df_1 = df_1.set_index('number', inplace = True)
df_2 = df_2.set_index('number', inplace = True)
df_3 = df_3.set_index('number', inplace = True)

df_list = [df_1, df_2, df_3]

for df in df_list :
    df = df.columns['New_name', 'New_Age']
```

This code returns :

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

when I'm using my real data

or

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

with the MWE above.

thanks

Comment: `df_1 = df_1.set_index('number', inplace = True)` is an assignment and an in-place operation. Pick one but you can't have both :)

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned below, that's unrelated to the error I'm trying to solve as it isnt used in my actual code.  Its redundant but doesnt cause an error

Comment: Sure it would. `inplace` returns `None` to the caller --> `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'columns'`. I'm not quite convinced that the code presented could throw `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'columns'`, though

Comment: Yeah so the none error is because I accidentally set `df = None`. If you change that and run the mwe it will return the second error that I was getting in my actual code. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In stead of these :

```
df_1 = df_1.set_index('number', inplace = True)
df_2 = df_2.set_index('number', inplace = True)
df_3 = df_3.set_index('number', inplace = True)
```

Only do this :

```
df_1.set_index('number', inplace = True)
df_2.set_index('number', inplace = True)
df_3.set_index('number', inplace = True)
```

`.set_index()` is inplace method and returns `None` but modified the object in place.

Also, inside the `for` loop, instead of this

```
df = df.columns['New_name', 'New_Age']
```

Do this :

```
df.columns = ['New_name', 'New_Age']
```

Comment: Ok thanks, was just throwing it together on the fly. I believe if you make that change and run the code again you'll still get the error specified

Comment: @Hugh_Kelley I updated the code to be changed inside for loop. It should work now !

Comment: aahhh, `df.columns["names"]` was my problem. `df.columns = ['names"]`  works like a charm